# RxJava: Can a result be split into two different observables?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have an observable that emits a single object which has two fields, something like this:

```
public class Details {
    private Link link;
    private List<Comment> comments;
}

Observable<Details> detailsObservable = ...;
```

Now, I was wondering: can this observable be somehow split into two observables? What I'd like to do is to have a subscriber listen for the `link` and another one to listen for `Comment`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map method to achieve that. Example code shared below, let me know if it helps.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<Details> dObs = Observable.just(new Details("a", "c"));
    Observable<String> lObs = dObs.map(d -> d.link);
    Observable<String> cObs = dObs.map(d -> d.comments);
    lObs.subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
    cObs.subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
}


static class Details {
    String link;
    String comments;

    public Details(String link, String comments) {
        this.link = link;
        this.comments = comments;
    }
}
```

Comment: don't forget to use either `share()` or `publish()` and `connect()` on base observable `dObs`
Otherwise, it would emit `Details` twice